# AES 256-bit gcm encryption on PHP side and decryption on JAVA side

Tags: java, php, android, encryption, aes

I am trying to use AES-256 bit GCM encryption, between PHP and Java. The problem is that I receive this exception on Java side on Android:

```
Decryption Error.!
javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: error:1e06e065:Cipher functions:aead_aes_gcm_open:BAD_DECRYPT
```

the code I am using:
on PHP side

```
$algo = 'aes-256-gcm';
$iv   = random_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($algo));
$key  = "secretKey12345678998765432112345"; // 256 bit 
$data = "HelloWorld";
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
 $data,
 $algo,
 $key,
 OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,
 $iv,
 $tag
);
echo base64_encode($key);
echo base64_encode($iv);
echo $ciphertext;
```

and on Java, Android, I am using this code:

```
static final int GCM_TAG_LENGTH = 16;
...
String decryptedText = null;
    byte[] encodedData = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decodediv = Base64.decode(iv, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(key, Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.e("data", new String(encodedData, 0));
    Log.e("iv", new String(decodediv, 0));
    Log.e("key", new String(decodedKey, 0));
    Log.d("test", "test");

    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");

    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey , new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_LENGTH * 8,decodediv));
        byte[] decodedData = c.doFinal(encodedData);
        decryptedText = new String(decodedData, "UTF-8");
        Log.e("MainActivity", "After decryption : "+ decryptedText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Decryption Error.!", e);
    }
    return decryptedText;
```

I am using php code from this page:

```
zimuel.it/blog/authenticated-encrypt-with-openssl-and-php-7-‌​1
```

I am using php v7.1.4

What could be the exception cause?

Comment: Where is `$tag` defined?  And what is it defined as?

Comment: I do not define $tag variable, this is from zimuel page: The authentication hash is stored in the $tag variable. This value is filled by the openssl_encrypt function and returned as reference. I am beginner in these sort of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it by myself, all I needed was to add $tag variable encoded in base64 to the end of encrypted message in PHP, because JAVA AES gcm implementation searches for tag, which I didn't provide earlier.

Comment: I have used the same solution, but still not working. I am still getting tag mismatch exception.Could you share your final solution